# Vector of custom struct in PyO3

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I'm new to Rust and PyO3 (coming from Python) so this might be obvious to more experienced people.

I declared a pyclass struct in PyO3.

```
#[pyclass]
struct Block {
    start: i32,
    stop: i32,
}
```

Then I use `Block` in a rust function that takes a vector of `Block` and outputs a vector of int (signature below)

```
#[pyfunction]
fn from_blocks(block_list: Vec<Block>) -> Vec<i32>
```

When I compile using `nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin` I get the following error:

```
#[pyfunction]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `pyo3::FromPyObject<'_>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<Block>`
```

How do I solve this?

**EDIT:**
Caio is right. I made a mistake in tracing back the error.
Previously I wrote

> Then I use Block in a rust function that takes a vector of int and outputs a vector of Block (signature below)

```
#[pyfunction]
fn to_blocks(list: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<Block>
```

But the actual offending function is:

```
#[pyfunction]
fn from_blocks(block_list: Vec<Block>) -> Vec<i32>
```

I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Sorry to confuse everyone. @Caio intuitively figured out that the offending function has the reverse signature. I've updated the question as a result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FromPyObject` is intended to be used by types that can be extracted from the Python world. That is why I think that you were trying to write `fn to_blocks(list: Vec<Block>) -> Vec<i32>` instead of `fn to_blocks(list: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<Block>`. If that is the case , lets go down to the implementation chain.

`FromPyObject` has a default implementation for [any &T that implements PyTryFrom](https://pyo3.rs/master/doc/pyo3/trait.FromPyObject.html#impl-FromPyObject%3C%27a%3E) and `PyTryFrom` has a default implementation for [any T that implements PyTypeInfo](https://pyo3.rs/master/doc/pyo3/prelude/trait.PyTryFrom.html#impl-PyTryFrom-1). `[pyclass]` implements `PyObjectAlloc` or `PyObjectWithFreeList` according to the [`impl_class`](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/blob/531f9db99e243678d7d4f48a1ff0a83e9695ea8b/pyo3-derive-backend/src/py_class.rs#L63) method and both traits have the `PyTypeInfo` trait bound. Therefore, your class/struct will work just fine with references, e.g.:

```
#[pyfunction]
fn to_blocks(list: Vec<&Block>) -> Vec<i32>
```

You can see in the official documentation this explanation in a summarized way.

> `FromPyObject` is implemented by various types that can be extracted
>   from a Python object **reference**.

Comment: Why would a function named `to_blocks` take a vector of blocks as input and return a vector of integers?

Comment: Despite the name, `fn to_blocks(list: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<Block>` compiles without issues and even if it didn't compile, the error would be different.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If it compiles without issues then why fix it? In any case, it doesn't make sense to suggest swapping the function's inputs and outputs as that wouldn't give OP what they need.

Comment: The compile error he gave in this question simply relates to the fact that custom derives aren't enough to enable a local owned type to be used in a function parameter. That is why I **suggested** that he **could** have written the wrong code and **if** that were the case, the above measures of this answer would be necessary. If I wasn't clear enough I can edit my post in a proper way.

Comment: Are you saying that the code he actually compiled is not the code shown in the question? If so, saying "your code should be" is confusing because it sounds like you're suggesting this would fix the problem.

Comment: @interjay, @caio apologies for the confusion. I think @caio figured out that I since I have a `fn to_blocks` then there's an opposite doing the reverse and that's what's giving the error.

Comment: Thank you kentwait. @interjay made some important statements that are now fixed.

Comment: pyo3 documentation still thin on this. It took quite a lot of googling to find this thread. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PyO3 are you on?
Your code is working for me on `0.5.3` and `0.6.0-alpha.1`.

Due to that I can't test this, but I would guess that you need to return a `PyResult`:

```rust
#[pyfunction]
fn to_blocks(list: Vec<i32>) -> PyResult<Vec<Block>>
```

Comment: `#[pyclass]` implements `IntoPyObject`/`ToPyObject`  for `Block`, that is why it works. OP code should probably be `fn to_blocks(list: Vec<Block>) -> Vec<i32>`.

Comment: @Caio I'm confused – since OP's code works, why should it be something else?

Comment: Because the error message he gave is the same error message one gets when `Block` is used as an input parameter. To be sure, I think it is best to wait his response about this matter.

Comment: @Caio you are right, I traced the error back to the wrong function. The error stems from `fn from_blocks(block_list: Vec<Block>) -> Vec<i32>`

Comment: @kentwait Thank you =)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the `pyfunction` attribute generates code that requires that the return type implements the `FromPyObject` trait. While there's a blanket implementation of `FromPyObject for Vec<T> where T: FromPyObject`, it looks like the code generated for `pyclass` attribute does not include an implementation of `FromPyObject` for your `Block` type.

Since I am unfamiliar with PyO3 other than the few minutes I just looked at its API documentation to validate this answer, I'm not sure how you'd best get a `FromPyObject` implementation -- perhaps there's a `derive` for it?